# Which gem for RSpec matchers should I use with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mongoid

It seems there are two gems that provide RSpec matchers to use with Mongoid.

Which is a better choice and why?

**MONGOID-RSPEC**
Evan Sagge's mongoid-rspec gem provides RSpec matchers for Mongoid. Includes matchers for associations, options, validations, and fields.
http://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec

**REMARKABLE-MONGOID**
Brian Cardarella's remarkable-mongoid gem provides RSpec matchers for Mongoid. It contains matchers just for Mongoid, plus all validation matchers fromRemarkable::ActiveModel.
http://github.com/bcardarella/remarkable_mongoid

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I don't think you should be using either. Specify the *behaviour* you expect from your code, not the *implementation* and your specs will be that much more meaningful.

What happens if you decide to switch from Mongoid to MongoMapper? Or back to ActiveRecord? You have to throw out the majority of your test suite and re-write it.

All those libraries do is direct you to do Development-Driven Testing, which is the complete antithesis of BDD/TDD.

Comment: Can you provide an alternative? Are you saying to skip out rspec completely and use cucumber? I am asking because swithing an app from mongo to mysql and using active record again is a pain.

Comment: My point is that you should probably just stick to using bare-bones RSpec, rather than any specific extensions. Your spec and Public API should (ideally) be technology agnostic.

Answer (score 9):

remarkable-mongoid's advantage is also, unfortunately, its disadvantage. The idea was to use the Remarkable ActiveModel matchers for the validators. This requires the alpha version of Remarkable 4.0. While Remarkable is a library of very high quality it also hasn't been touched since last June. This is a huge issue with my library, the main dependency hasn't left alpha in over 8 months! I pinged several of the devs and never heard back from any of them.

As for which of the two libraries is better, a quick look at the README it seems like mongoid-rspec has more features. However, I have never used it and cannot speak about any experience with it.

All this being said, to be perfectly honest (even though I wrote one of the libraries) I think both are pretty bullshit. Unfortunately Shoulda started this useless style of testing of validations and associations and everybody has followed suit. (myself included) In pretty much every case writing the test is just a duplication of effort of writing the actual code. You're not really testing anything at all. At the very best they can be seen a sanity check. At worst they are a complete waste of time.

I suggest asserting the behavior in different parts of the test suite.

Comment: Very candid answer, thanks! And informative. Do you suggest writing Cucumber scenarios instead? Is that what you mean by "asserting the behavior in different parts of the test suite"?

Comment: Well, using these matchers is useless because you're adding functionality without any context. For example, you should only add an association between two models when your code requires it. When your app attempts to use that association because of a test then it will fail. Then you add the association to satisfy the test. This way you have a much more flexible test framework. If you relied on the Shoulda-like matchers you end up with this super brittle test framework. You should be writing code, not wrestling with your test suite.

Comment: Brian - I agree 100% re: associations, but the validation matchers I've seen spec behavior (messages in errors, etc). Without validation specs, how do you like to drive validations into existence?

Comment: @dave I still think many of the validation matchers out there are too tightly coupled to the ORM of choice. Is asserting the error message really specing behavior?